# Error MT5306: Failed to create the a fat library. Please review the build log

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Getting this error after updating VS and XCode.

`Error MT5306: Failed to create the a fat library. Please review the build log.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Run the above command in terminal will solve the issue.